# Google maps api not displaying in fancybox

Tags: jquery, google-maps, fancybox

I am able to print a Google map with php.
However when I try to display it in a fancybox (works fine) it displays a part of the map at the top left corner and the rest is just grey.

The code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $('.fancybox').fancybox({

      'hideOnContentClick': false, // so you can handle the map
'overlayColor'      : '#ccffee',
  'overlayOpacity'    : 0.8,
  'autoDimensions': true, // the selector #mapcontainer HAS css width and height
       'aftershow': function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

      }
     });
      });   




 jQuery(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);


// Multiple Markers
var markers =['description', 35.179649, 25.708952],];


// Info Window Content
var infoWindowContent = [
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>desvription</h3>' +
    '<p>Blah blah blah......</p>' +
    '</div>'],       
];

// Display multiple markers on a map
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });

    // Allow each marker to have an info window    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

// Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(14);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});

}
    </script>
```

the link to show the map

```
<div class="googlemaptitle"><a class="fancybox" href="#viewthemap" title="View the map">View the map</a></div>
```

the div that prints the map (hidden)

```
<div id="viewthemap" style="width:800px; height:780px; display: none;">
    <div id="map_wrapper">
<div id="map_canvas" class="mapping"></div>
```

the result in fancybox
[image]

Also how do i change the markers icon at the google map with an icon from my server?

Comment: version of fancybox? ... I guess is v2.x because the graphic, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If using fancybox v2.x, try

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    //'hideOnContentClick': false, // v1.3.4
    //'overlayColor': '#ccffee', // v1.3.4
    //'autoDimensions': true, // v1.3.4
    //'overlayOpacity': 0.8, // v1.3.4
    // for v2.x use the following API options :
    closeClick: false, // so you can handle the map
    autoSize: true,
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(204, 255, 238, 0.8)'
            }
        }
    },
    beforeShow: function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

    }
});
```

Comment: the version I use is  * version: 2.1.5 the above code does not work as it doesn't show the fancybox at all

Comment: @AntonisVergetakis : the code above is for v2.x and it's the fancybox part only that you have to replace from your code above

Comment: I already replaced the code and in the fancybox part and although it triggers the fancybox the div is not displayed at all

Comment: when the fancybox re sizes it shows the map but it is not centered

Comment: I just found out the problem is the display:none at the hidden div. (<div id="viewthemap" style="width:800px; height:780px; display: none;">). I removed the display none it works fine , but how else can I hide this content? Ay ideas?

Comment: @AntonisVergetakis : try wrapping in a parent hidden `div`

Comment: I firstly used visibility:collapse and did work fine. After I load all its content from a new page into an iframe with the parameter iframe in fancybox. Thanks any way for your help.

Answer (score -2):

This is the problem if you open map in div as fancy box..

The solution is you need to refresh the page after close the fancybox..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#fancyBoxLink").fancybox({
        'href'   : '#MyMapDIV',
        'titleShow'  : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
        'afterClose':function () {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
 });
```

Check also this post

[fancybox on google map marker example](http://www.developersnote.com/2014/01/fancybox-on-google-map-marker-example.html)